Why show simplified Chinese text even I set "zh-tw" locale?
I write JSF and use primefaces, and found it show simplified Chinese text even I set "zh-tw" locale.
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="jakarta.faces.core">

<h:body>
    <f:view locale="zh-tw">
        <ui:include src="/component/breadcrumb.xhtml"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{text['titleText']}"/>
        <div class="card">
            <h:form id="form">
                <p:dataTable var="article" value="#{dtArticleView.articles}" lazy="false">
                    <p:column headerText="#{text['titleText']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{article.title}" />
                    </p:column>
        
                    <p:column headerText="#{text['summaryText']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{article.summary}" />
                    </p:column>
        
                    <p:column headerText="#{text['categoryText']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{article.category}" />
                    </p:column>
        
                    <p:column headerText="#{text['statusText']}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{article.status}" />
                    </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </f:view>
</h:body>

When it's empty, it showed: "无相关数据。".
But "無相關數據".
Where is traditional Chinese text?
Screenshot: https://github.com/orgs/primefaces/discussions/2707
I don't know this problem is from jakarta, TomEE or primefaces.
Tried: faces-config default-local, FacesContext setLocale and f:view locale.
Expect: Give me traditional Chinese.
